# Adding Font Into Webview

Tags: android, fonts, webview

I am creating a webview app. I added the font in assets folder. And I'm using css code to make it work. But The font is not loading into webview. The Unicode blocks are not showing in my webview app. Link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisu_(Unicode_block)
And here are the code I am using now.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
    String html = "<html><head><style>@font-face {@font-family: 'Conv_LISU'; src: url('file:///android_asset/font/LISU.ttf');} body, button, input, label, select, td, tr, textarea,li,ul,span,div,table,h1,h2,h3,h4{ font-family:Conv_LISU;}</style></head>";

    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {
            // Handle the error
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

    webView.setInitialScale(1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
    webView.loadUrl("http://google.com");


}
```

}

Comment: What exactly is your question ?

Comment: The font is not loading into webview and the unicode blocks are not appearing in the webview.

Answer (score 0):

Loading another URL would erase the HTML content you first put into the web view and thus the CSS Styles.

I think the only way you may be able to do it is either using javascript to inject it  `view.loadUrl("javascript:script to apply css here")` after the view is loaded.

Or you could manually download the HTML Page requested, inject the CSS Code and then feed it into the webview which will load the assets for the original page as well:)